# Meaning of "not that I'm complaining"

Tags: grammar, american-english

What's the meaning of this sentence? What's the grammar? "not that I'm complaining". I am offering some good benefits to my friend. Then this sentence appears in his response, which makes me confused. Does he like the benefits I gave? I guess he appreciates it, but he thinks that's too much?
He is going to work in another place for several weeks. Then I told him I can help him to book a hotel and other stuff. So if he was complaining, it means he doesn't like the things I offered.

He also said "well, maybe I'll consider it."

Comment: It means "I'm complaining".

Comment: @HotLicks He doesn't like the benefits? Oops

Comment: Look up *litotes*. (That should form the basis of an answer, but it's late and I'll give it to someone else.)

Comment: It's not really a full sentence in itself, though it may sometimes be punctuated as one. I'd prefer a bit more context before essaying an answer.

Comment: It's highly context-dependent.

Comment: @Hot Licks I'd say it's impossible to be sure from the information. Say your friend expected $18 from you, and you gave him a twenty and said, don't worry about the 2 bucks. He says "Not that I'm complaining". That wouldn't mean he's complaining necessarily

Comment: @Zebrafish - Yeah, as I said later it's highly context-dependent.

Comment: @AndrewLeach tks

Comment: my research:   litotes - a literary device

Litotes is a figure of speech consisting of an understatement in which an affirmative is expressed by negating its opposite.

As in:

    "This is no small problem" for it's a big problem.

    "She was not a little upset" for she was extremely upset.

    "My friend responded: Not that I am complaining" for he's  complaining!  (his friend did say he would consider it)

Comment: @Ibf The last step of that chain doesn't follow the logic of the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) "Not that I am complaining" when used without a "but" or other negative qualification, usually means what it says. It means that he is ***not*** complaining, though in some contexts you might *think* he is. He is reassuring you that he is quite satisfied with whatever he is referring to. Example:

> "this train is quite slow, not that I am complaining: it allows me to finish my homework before I get home!"

It can also mean something was "very welcome" as in

> "I got promoted by mistake. Not that I'm complaining, you understand: it seems they can't deny me once they've made the decision."

It can be used to make it clear that a particular statement is not a complaint:

> "My wife makes pasta every day. Not that I'm complaining; it tastes great!"

It is also used to imply that one was lucky to escape with the less damaging outcome, or that "it could have been worse", as in

> our roof got blown away in the hurricane. Not that I am complaining: if the winds had been a little stronger the whole house could have fallen down.
>
> Mike broke both arms and both legs in the bike accident. Not that he is complaining: he is lucky to be alive!

(2) It is sometimes used to refer to **what one is getting for free**, with the meaning that one should not complain about what one gets free of cost, which may possibly be relevant to your case:

> My mother-in-law's house is small and cramped. Not that I am complaining: she lets us live with her for free.
>
> This mobile phone is not a top class model. Not that I am complaining, since I won it on a 50 cents ticket in the college lottery!

(3) However, the use of "but" will subtly change the meaning: "not that I am complaining, ***but***..." can be used to preface and "soften" an actual complaint or criticism as noted in the [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/437328/231519) by user30031.

Examples:

> "Not that I am complaining, but you certainly play that stereo loud enough to wake the dead"
>
> "Not that I am complaining, but my children create some terrific confusion every weekend."

(4) Also sometimes used sarcastically or ironically before an outright or outrageous complaint:

> Not that I am complaining, but my boss has the ethics of a chimpanzee and the brains of a flea.

[A chimpanzee in the wild has no ethics and the implication is that a flea has no brains.]

Comment: Thank you for the effort of answering the question. I appreciate it.

Comment: You are most welcome @user3289; I really enjoyed writing this answer and learned a lot in the process!

Answer (score 0):

Taken at face-value, this phrase usually means "I would like to offer criticism about you, but I don't want to offend you or seem ungrateful".